# Authentication error in Twitter API access using Python

Tags: python, authentication, twitter

I have a bigger pipeline I'm trying to feed with searching tweets, but have narrowed down to an authentication error. I pay for Basic API access. I have tried regenerating all of my keys, to no avail.

```py
import tweepy
api_key = "my_api_key"
api_secrets = "my_api_secrets"
access_token = "my_access_token"
access_token_secret = "my_access_token_secrets"

# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secrets)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print('Successful Authentication')
except:
    print('Failed authentication')
```

Yields the following error in PyCharm:

> Failed authentication

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure you have copied the correct API key, API secret, access token, and access token secret from the Twitter developer dashboard. Verify that there are no extra spaces or characters in the keys and tokens.

2 - Ensure that you have installed the tweepy package correctly. You can install it using pip:

```
pip install tweepy
```

3 - Ensure that your Twitter Developer Account is properly set up and you have access to the Basic API. Verify that your application is correctly linked to your Developer Account and that it has the necessary permissions to access the Twitter API.

4 - Make sure your system's clock is set to the correct date and time.

5 - Update your code to catch the TweepError and print the specific error message:

```
try:
  api.verify_credentials()
  print('Successful Authentication')
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
  print('Failed authentication:', e)
```